# Spring cloud task on data flow server vs @EnableTask

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I am new to Spring cloud data flow. Trying to figure out what it mean by registering, creating a task on spring cloud data flow server vs running a spring class with annotation @EnableTask
Any clarification to understand what these two are, will be helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Spring Cloud Task, you'd build and test standalone Task microservices in isolation. With the programming model, you can address use-cases ranging from ETL/ELT, data migration, or predictive-model-training etc.

Once you have an "n" no. of such applications, you could use Spring Cloud Data Flow's [DSL](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_composed_tasks_dsl) to compose them into coherent Task/Batch pipelines. To use them in the DSL, you'd have to first register the coordinates of the standalone Task Apps.

Refer to the SCDF's [Task overview](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-task) and as well as the [Task Developer Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#task-dev-guide) for more details - you could repeat it locally to follow along and learn the mechanics.

Comment: Can a task put message to queue - say RabbitMQ?

Comment: You could use Spring Batch's [AmqpItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/amqp/AmqpItemWriter.html) in your Task App to publish events to RabbitMQ. Also, if you are interested in Task lifecycle events, see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-task-events). Likewise, you could launch a Task from [events](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-launch-tasks-from-stream), too.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information! 
Actually, I am still trying to deploy a sample spring batch job jar with main class having @EnableTask on to the local data flow server. I think post I can register/create task on it. Correct?

Comment: Yes, if the Task/Batch App runs locally (via `java -jar`), it should work in SCDF, too. You'd simply register the maven:// or file:// coordinates of the Jar file and create a Task definition with it in SCDF. I'd still recommend repeating the "Task Developer Guide" (see link in the post above) - if you make that work end to end, you can then switch to the custom Batch App.

Comment: Thank you!! I could run a batch application as task on SCDF. Now I am trying to run https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/ tutorial on SCDF but getting error ----> Failed to start bean 'taskLifecycleListener'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TaskExecution, ID 11 not found